# Efficient way to wait for completion of Runnable tasks in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I have n-number of `Runnable` tasks  (not Callable) that I am executing with ExecutorService.

I want to wait for all the tasks to complete.

I can't use `invokeAll` - because it works for collection of Callables.

I can't use `shutdown()+awaitTermination`, because awaittermination requires to provide a time out, but my tasks can take hours to complete.

I can use:

```
ExecutorService.shutdown();             
while (!ExecutorService.isTerminated()) {}
```

But this loop will be always triggered.

What is suggested in such scenario?

Answer (score 4):

`ExecutorService.awaitTermination()` returns a `boolean` which indicates if the executor terminated or the timeout has elapsed. You can ofcourse call it in a loop:

```
ExecutorService executor = ...;

executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.awaitTermination(24L, TimeUnit.HOURS)) {
    System.out.println("Still waiting for the executor to finish");
}

System.out.println("Executor finished");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ExecutorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.HOURS);`

Comment: In my post I've specifically wrote why I can't use it.

Comment: In my version of Java TimeUnit doesn't have HOUR or DAY

Comment: Use SECONDS, Long.MAX_VALUE of seconds = 106751991167300 days

Answer (score 1):

For known number of tasks the [CountDownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is just perfect but there are cases, when you don't know how many tasks you will have, in that case I use [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). For Example:

```
    Semaphore s =new Semaphore(0);
    while(..){
     if (isLastTask){
         taskExecutor.execute(new Task(s));
     } else 
         taskExecutor.execute(new Task());
    }
    s.acquire(1);

class Task implement implements Runnable {
   Semaphore s;

   public Task(){
     this(null);
   }

   public Task (Semaphore s){
     this.s = s;
   }

   public void run(){
       ......
      if ( s != null )
          s.release();
   }
}
```

Comment: The while loop has to be closed before the class declaration.